# Difference between server Jobs and Workers?

Tags: server, distributed-computing, distributed-development, queueing

I am trying to understand the difference between server workers and server jobs. Google has not been very helpful because the keyword "jobs" is being construed as an employment term... I have yet to find an article answering my question. :/

Would someone please elaborate on the distinction between server jobs and workers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "job" generally refers to a specific task that needs to be performed, that will take some time to perform, where the amount of time needed is great enough, that someone decide to turn it into a "job." A "worker" is an object that performs some task. It's task might be to execute a job. Generally, a worker performs a task, finishes, then becomes available for another task. But this terminology is all vague.